# How to export all data and data field from SugarCRM?

Tags: export, sugarcrm

Very new in to SugarCRM, and want to understand all the data and linkages across different modules in SugarCRM. Is there a way to export all the data, data labels, and relationships across all the modules? Want to have a high level overview of information in SugarCRM.

Would really appreciate some help and advice, thanks!

Comment: I have SugarCRM installed on my Synology NAS and it is running off MariaDB.  I was able to view tables and other structures by using phpMyAdmin.